# mouseenter JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, css

hi there i have this code, and its not working , I dont understand why

```
$('#thumbs > li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find("div").fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).find("div").fadeOut();
});
​
```

here is the whole thing http://jsfiddle.net/8Q24N/

Comment: `not working`... very descriptive, also what's the point of posting a fiddle if you're not going to set it up properly?

Comment: What do you mean, setting up properly?

Comment: And what should be the title be, if its not working, the same code is working here http://jsfiddle.net/wdAzE/8/

Comment: your fiddle uses mootools, but the code seems to require jQuery

Comment: Ohhh, I had no idea about, that, sorry, I didnt know. now I know, thank you

Comment: @Musa Ah, c'mon. The demo has a cute cat picture. What more do you need? `:P`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbs > li').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find("div").fadeIn();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).find("div").fadeOut();
    });
});​
```

Wrap the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/8Q24N/4/).

Comment: Is there any way I can have two of this <div class="thumb-container2">bzzz</div> and one <div class="thumb-container2">Dezz</div>. ONe on right side of the picture one on left side of the screen, showing at the same time

Comment: or show one on top of the other

Comment: Thank you, I actually got it